# How to avoid line break in conditional text in BI Publisher RTF

Tags: rtf

I have added condition region,  if Harmon_ID7> " " , to show "HTS:" value of Harmon_ID7. if  B_ID31 > " " , to show "BTS:" value of B_ID31.

C HTS: Harmon_ID7     ECC BTS: B_ID31EC

But "HTS:", value of Harmon_ID7 printing in one row and "BTS:", value of value of B_ID31EC printing in another row.

Expected Results: HTS: H1      BTS: B1

But the result is:

HTS: H1
BTS: B1

How can i have both HTS and BTS printed in same line with the condition .